# How to "stack" an ISPF command?

Tags: mainframe, zos, rexx, ispf

I have this rexx exec:

```
/* rexx */                              
address ispexec                         
"select pgm(isrdslst) parm(UDL ~)"
```

And I would lijke to have it invoke the `/` command immediately after it starts to open the OMVS command interface (like the ISPF Option 6 interface for TSO Commands).

I've tried this prior to the `select` with no joy:

```
zcmd = '/'
'vput (zcmd)'
```

Note: On the ISPF Command line I can enter `udlist ~;/` and that works.

Comment: I’m thinking something with CONTROL NONDISPL might be helpful here.

Comment: I had tried 'control nondispl enter' after setting the zcmd variable without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Marv Knight for this solution - not exactly what I was looking for but it may be the only way it works:

```
/* rexx */                               
ADDRESS ISPEXEC                          
cmd = "UDLIST /;/"                       
 "DISPLAY PANEL(ISPBLANK) COMMAND(CMD)"
```

The only “problem” using this as an option from a primary menu is that you return to the TBDISPL for the UDLIST and not immediately back to the primary menu.

Comment: If there isn't an easy, flexible way to do this within ISPF, it might be worth looking into any scripting/macro facilities your 3270 emulator provides.